# How to ask/phrase questions concerning the attributes of a particular language

Tags: discussion

A while back I posted a question asking which portions of an xml node are read first when using C#. My reasoning behind this was that for my particular use case it didn't really matter whether I put my intended value in the name, attribute, or innertext, i just needed which ever was read first (i.e. fastest) because i would be doing thousands of read/comparisons.

As anyone who has used StackOverflow for a while could probably guess, the question was quickly flagged as not being specific, downvoted, and then deleted. While that was going on, there was the normal plethora of "what did your benchmarks and tests show?" questions.

So my question is how do I ask these foresight based questions? Sure I don't have a "problem" per se because I thought of my potential issues ahead of time and am trying to tailor my solution around them.

This is a very similar problem to all the closed "best-practice" questions that you see when trying to plan out a project. Ask a question before you start and you get your hand slapped and your question thrown out, but if you arbitrarily pick a direction and wait until in it inevitably crashes then ask you question, people will trip over themselves providing solutions all while asking "why did you choose to do it this way?" or "everyone knows you supposed to do _____".

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is how do I ask these foresight based questions? Sure I don't have a "problem" per se because I thought of my potential issues ahead of time and am trying to tailor my solution around them.

That's exactly what benchmarking is for. Don't ask people to try and predict from your descriptions which approach will be better. Benchmark your code and find out for sure.

Comment: For some questions sure, but not questions such as these which are not dependent on content, machine, or user. There is only one right answer, and telling people that they should benchmark or test it is a lazy way of saying you don't know the answer and is not helpful for the person asking the question or anyone else reading the question hoping to find an answer to their own similar problem.

Comment: @BenW301 Asking other people is a lazy way of saying you don't want to test and benchmark your ideas. It's not our job to be helpful to people who don't want to do the most basic testing.

Comment: @BenW301 and asking for that answer without doing the benchmark yourself ISN'T laziness?

Comment: @Patrice It isn't practical, there are very few programmers that have to time to build out an entire separate test case for every design challenge they come across. I can go into any forum for any language and without even understanding the question, post a lazy "well try it and see what happens" or a "try every other possible solution and see if that works" style answer. If you don't know the answer, don't post. If you don't think it's worth your time, don't post. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @BenW301 If you can't plan your own projects and account for testing in them, it's not on us. The fact that it's "not practical" to test it yourself, is in no way Stack's problem. Find forums that have less strict rules about that kind of question, ask it there. Stack is NOT the only resource in the world. As a coder, you should understand that the right tool should be used for the right problem.

Comment: The problem @Patrice is that there are two kinds of people on stackflow, those that are there to help each other and answer reasonable questions and those who hope to be spoon fed easy questions to that they can quickly answer and get points, if they encounter a hard question they look for ways to disqualify it so that they can't still get their points and won't feel as bad about not knowing the answer. I'm not looking for people like you to waste your time running your own tests, I am looking for someone who actually knows the answer (and there is only one) to post based on their expertise.

Comment: @BenW301 funny how you say your question is hard, but, since it could be solved by some testing, I see it as asking for a "spoon-fed answer"(ie : " I could do it myself to really learn, or have someone give me the answer so I can use it straight"). In any case, I can peg this down to difference of opinion. I don't see a positive way for you or I that this conversation will end, and it'll only aggravate both, AND Bill (who's getting notified). Just remember that before you ask, you are expected to research, INCLUDING tests. Or you can ask on other forums :). In any case. Have a good day ^^

Comment: Well @Patrice this is where you and Bill need to read more carefully before answering.  My question was not which runs fastest but which gets run first, the first question is, you're right, easy and something that is on me to prove/demonstrate, the second is something that after a lot of research i couldn't find the answer to and something a potential reader either knows or doesn't. My whole point of THIS question is how to word questions that are inherently complicated and may appear lazy but have an answer that cannot be easy discovered by the asker, even with benchmarks.

Comment: @BenW301 Your question, [Reading Element Names vs Reading Element Attributes: Speed C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28575389/1288), was very much about performance issues.